# change default home folder application for ctrl+super+E

Tags: nautilus, filemanager

I went to keyboard application to set a shortcut for the home folder (set to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> as default) but for some reason it launches `pcmanfm` and not `nautilus`.

I tried several things such as edit files in `/usr/share/applications` or `gksudo nautilus /usr/share/applications`, but I can't find where is the setting that launches pcmanfm (at the files I can see `Exec=nautilus %U`).

i'm using Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In Settings go to Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts (along the side)
- Click the little `+` button
- In the little window that pops up, give it a name and the command `nautilus`. (By default it will open the home folder. You can specify
  a path to a folder if you like.)
- Click OK
- Click on 'Disabled' and set it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> by holding the keys and releasing them.
- Click 'All Settings' along the top.
- Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>

Let me know how it goes :)

Comment: If it still launches pcmanfm then look through your shortcuts to see what is using that key combo.

Comment: 1. custom shortcuts working, but it's not the standard way to configure file manager shortcut. i prefer changing the configuration for "home folder" shortcut in "launchers" menu.

Comment: Maybe you should note what DE your are using & what Xbuntu release. The default in Ubuntu 12.10 in both a ubuntu (unity) & gnome (gnome-shell) session for the home keyboard launcher is "Explorer" which generally means `Alt+Home`, not Ctrl+super+e

Comment: I don't have xubuntu but i've installed xfce so i guess it changed something.
but this one helped me, Alt+Home is running nautilus.
Thanks!